# Why aren't my functions running?

Tags: c++, function, input, vector, output

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to get the hang of this C++ assignment. I'm supposed to read a file and put it into a vector, sort it, and then output it in a new file in 3 separate nonmember functions, but for some reason they won't run. There is never a new file outputted and I even put the done cout in there to test if the function was running at all, but I just get nothing every time. If I could get some help it would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "stdafx.h"


using namespace std;

void readtoVector(vector<string>& weblog)
{
    string line;

    fstream myFile;
    myFile.open("weblog.txt");
    if (myFile.fail()){
        cerr << "File not available" << endl;
    }
    if (myFile.is_open()){
        for (line; getline(myFile, line);){
            weblog.push_back(line);
        }
        myFile.close();
    }

}

void sortVector(vector<string>& weblog)
{
    sort(weblog.begin(), weblog.end());

}

void writeVector(const vector<string>& weblog)
{
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open("newWeblog.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i > weblog.size; ++i){
        myFile << weblog[i] << endl;
    }
    myFile.close();

    cout << "done";
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> weblog;
    readtoVector(weblog);
    sortVector(weblog);
    writeVector(weblog);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Edit:fixed the reference issue in readtoVector

Comment: As I recall, the inclusion of `stdafx.h` should be the first line of code. Why you're using a precompiled header for this little code baffles me, but if memory serves, it's not in the right place.

Comment: When you single-stepped through the statements with a debugger, what information did you discover?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to use a reference for the argument to `readtoVector`. That function is operating on a local copy of the vector; the original remains empty.

Comment: I fixed it but I'm still not getting any output.

Answer (score 2):

In `void readtoVector(vector<string> weblog)` you send a copy of the vector into function instead of the actual one and then populate the container in the function. Thus when the function call returns, the vector is returned back to heap.

You should send the reference like you did with the other functions:

```
void readtoVector(vector<string>& weblog)
```

Besides that your code didn't compile. The line

```
for (int i = 0; i > weblog.size; ++i){
```

in function `void writeVector()` has requested the vectors size. You should call the member function `size()` instead of requesting it directly. Also your condition won't evaluate to true. It should be `<` instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < weblog.size(); ++i)
```

Fixing this, your code works perfectly fine on my machine using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I fixed it but I'm still not getting any output.

Answer (score 1):

The following line in `writeVector()` shouldn't compile:

```
for (int i = 0; i > weblog.size; ++i){
```

I think you want this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < weblog.size(); ++i){
```

Note that `size()` is a member function and needs the function call operator and the loop condition should be `less than`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that should compile. function -> function pointer -> `bool` -> `int`, which can be compared.

Comment: @chris: I tested with g++ and VS2013 and both emit an error for that. It may be too many conversions in a row.

Comment: I didn't think there was a limit for standard conversions. Interesting, though. I also meant member function (pointer), which is probably why it doesn't work. I also just realized you're not allowed to compare pointers and integers.

Comment: @chris: I'm just guessing based off [this information](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast). I'm not enough of a language-lawyer to quote the standard on this (and I'm too lazy).